# NullPointer exeption when retrieving data from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I try to retrive data from firebase database 
but i have null pointer exeption 
here is my model code

```
class Request {
    var Name: String? = null
    var Phone: String? = null
    var Street: String? = null
    var Home:String?= null
    var Flat:String?=null
    var Status: String?=null  
}
```

Here is how i retrieve data

```
var mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        for (d in p0.children) {
            var modelRequest: Request? = d.child("Requests").child(user.toString()).getValue(Request::class.java)
            var ord: Order? =d.child("Orders").getValue(Order::class.java)
            Log.d("loadedList", "ok")
            requestList.add(modelRequest!!)

        }

    }
})
```

Here is my data structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're looking over the top-level nodes in your database (`Food`, `Requests`, etc) and then getting the `Requests` child node of each. Since there is no `/Requests/Requests` that will always be `null`.

This should be closer:

```
override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
    var modelRequest: Request? = snapshot.child("Requests").child(user.toString()).getValue(Request::class.java)
    var ord: Order? =snapshot.child("Orders").getValue(Order::class.java)
    Log.d("loadedList", "ok")
    requestList.add(modelRequest!!)
}
```

Note that you're now loading all the data from your database, to then only use the `Requests` and `Orders` nodes. This is a waste of bandwidth, so you really should only request the data you need. You could do this by attaching two listeners and waiting for the result of both.